# Issues with a CSS Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css

I've built a dropdown menu using CSS. All the positioning is right, and it looks great. But it's not possible to click the submenu options. The submenu appears while the cursor is over the button leading to the dropdown, but once the cursor is moved down, to try and click a link, the menu disappears. I've tried changing the z-index and the positioning, but it doesn't seem to be working.

(There are two drop down submenus, one after the other, but the site won't let me post the html code. #navigation refers to the entire navigation bar, menu is the div that wraps both submenus and sub_menu is each individual submenu)
The css code is:

```
#navigation { width: 100%; background: #1C140D; /*BUTTONS*/ }
#navigation ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
#navigation ul li { list-style-type: none; display: inline; color:#1C140D; }
#navigation li a { display: block; float: left; padding: 5px 10px; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF; }
#navigation li a:hover { background: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }
#content-container { float: left; width: 100%; height: 175px; background: #FFFFFF url(/wp-content/uploads/layout-three-fixed-background.gif) repeat-y 100% 0; color: #F2E9E1; }
ul { font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 14px; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
ul li { display: block; position: relative; float: left; color: #1C140D; }
li ul {display:none; }
ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #1C140D; border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; background: #1C140D; /*BUTTONS*/ margin-left: 1px; white-space: nowrap; }
ul li a:hover { background:#1C140D; }
li:hover ul { display: block; }
ul.sub_menu { position:absolute; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF; color: #1C140D; top: 30px; }
li:hover li { float: none; font-size: 14px; color: #1C140D; }
li:hover a { background: #1C140D; color: #FFFFFF; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #1C140D; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enlarge the lead buttom and add in it the submenu list.
Or try to move the submenu few pixels under the lead buttom, and the hover{display} to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.sub_menu {
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #1C140D;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Your problem is with this line, you're pushing your submenu dropdown too far from your parent menu item, so to fix it just change `top:30px` to `top:100%` to position your submenu exactly 100% from your menu item and it should be fixed.

```
ul.sub_menu {
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #1C140D;
    top: 100%;
}
```